# android - detect a touch on the screen while video is running

Tags: android, video, touch-event

I am a beginner and I have two question.

1. Why does the video in the attached code is not running (get a message from the emulator that the application cannot run the video).
2. Can anyone please help me to understand how should I implement the onTouchEvent in order to capture a touch on the screen (don't care where on the screen) while a video is running.

Thanks in advance
Amihay

> public class VidShow extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.videoscrn);

/*run the video*/
VideoView video = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);

// Load and start the movie
video.setVideoPath("raw/samplevideo.3gp" );
video.start();

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend VideoView and implement [`VideoView.onTouchEvent(..)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html#onTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29).